# How to manipulate jsonl objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jsonlines

Given an API that returns a `jsonl`, how can I manipulate the data that I obtain?

What if the API gives me data like this:

```
{"plate": "pizza", "quantity": 3}
{"plate": "pasta", "quantity": 2}
```

1. In javascript the object retrieved what type will have?
2. If I want to add a new object, to have a result like:

```
{"plate": "pizza", "quantity": 3}
{"plate": "pasta", "quantity": 2}
{"plate": "hotdog", "quantity": 7}
```

How can I do that maintaining the type `.jsonl` and not creating and array?

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: What do you mean by "what type will have"? None of the examples seem to be valid JSON, may you make sure they are correct?

Comment: JSON Lines does not use commas between lines, and the lines must be complete valid JSON strings. In your case, they are not valid: the property names need double-quotes.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes, this is a doc about them https://jsonlines.org.

Comment: @Pointy ok, I corrected the question. but still, how I manage them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [jsonlines.org](https://jsonlines.org), each line in a jsonl file is a valid JSON value.

Thus, the approach would seem to be:

1. split the file into lines.
2. parse each line separately as JSON.

Something like this:

```js
const lines = data.split(/\n/);
lines.forEach(line => {
  const object = JSON.parse(line);
  // Do something with object.
});
```

Comment: This is correct, but the big advantage to the format is the ability to *stream* the content and only parse one object at a time.